# How to use "AS" in Grafana in the Cloudwatch query

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I use Grafana and CloudWatch

Here is my code in Grafana

```
SELECT
    AVG(CPUUtilization)
FROM
    "AWS/EC2"
WHERE
    AutoScalingGroupName = 'default'
```

This query result is 20

But I want multi value in query result, like:

```
SELECT
    AVG(CPU) AS cpu,
    30 AS lat,
    15 AS lon
FROM
    "AWS/EC2"
```

Example, `cloudwatch query => result => 20,30,15`

How to sovle this problem?

Comment: Your query with `lat` and `lon` is valid - what's the issue?

Comment: It's not work. I want to know why It doesn't work /
error message => "Invalid syntax near '30 AS lat\\r'\\n"

Comment: Do you have double-escaped line-breaks in your SQL strings? Grafana doesn't have its own SQL engine (AFAIK), it uses SQL Server, so the problem may lie elsewhere. If it is SQL SErver then get an XEvents trace so you can see the actual SQL being executed.

Comment: erro message => ,30 AS lat,15 AS lon  FROM  \\\"...'\\n\\t    

 my query =>  ||SELECT AVG(CPUUtilization),30 AS lat,15 AS lon  FROM  'AWS/EC2'  WHERE  AutoScalingGroupName = '_default'||
  Is it a cloudwatch error?

Comment: I don't know, sorry - this is beyond my area.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `SQL`, but only `Metric Insight query`. It doesn't support that. See doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-metrics-insights-querylanguage.html

Comment: Can't I return 3 values in metric query?